# Error : document.queryselector is not a function

Tags: button, vuejs2, document, selectors-api, mounted-volumes

In the code below, the button labeled **Add More** is not functioning as expected. Ideally it should add the input value to the unordered list on the page. Instead, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.queryselector is not a function

**Page Code**

```
<div id="root">
    <input type="text" id="input" v-model="message"/>

    <p>The value of the input is : {{message}}</p>

    <ul>
        <li v-for="n in names" v-text="n"></li>
    </ul>

    <input id="input1" type="text"/>

    <button id="button"> Add More </button>
</div>

<script>
    var app = new Vue ({
        el : '#root',
        data : {
            message : 'Hello World!',
            favourite : 'author',
            names : ['Sunil' , 'Anis' , 'Satyajit']
        },
    });

    document.queryselector('#button').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        var n = document.queryselector('#input1');
        app.names.push(n.value);
        n.value = '';
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its `document.querySelector`. Note the capital S in `querySelector`.

You also have a mispelling with `addEventListner`. It should be `addEventListener`.

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected it. Still it's not working.

Comment: @SFDC_Learner care to expand on that? You still get querySelector is not a function?

Comment: Please find I have updated the code removing mounted part. It is still not working and says below error.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: document.queryselector is not a function

Comment: @SFDC_Learner You're using that method twice, if you were to replace both of them it should fix your problem.

Comment: @SFDC_Learner you still have queryselector with a lower case S in other parts of the code.

Comment: Thanks! Oh my God, I didn't know it's case sensitive!